# How to get float value (i.e. 92.91%) from [u' 92.91%\n '] in python

Tags: python

When I use this code:

```
elements = [u'  92.91%\n ', u'  98.71%\n ' ,u'  93.81%\n ']
scores = []
for element in elements:
    scores.append(float(element.text))
return scores
```

I get an error as:

> `ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 92.91%`

Comment: `[float(elem.strip()[:-1]) for elem in elements]`

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the numerical part, you can do `scores = [float(element.strip()[:-1]) for element in elements]` which takes the spacing off the sides and the `%` off the end. If you want the *actual* number, just do `scores = [float(element.strip()[:-1]) / 100.0 for element in elements]`.

(Thanks to viraptor for the following point):

If you want to be more clear about removing the `%`, you can say `element.strip().rstrip("%")`, which strips it of all whitespace and then strips all percent signs off the right side.

Comment: why do you divide in 100?

Comment: @alfasin because the percentage means "of 100"

Comment: Nice that you think outside the box, but that wasn't asked by the OP!

Comment: @alfasin *shrug* I feel like if OP just does my first method and multiplies the numbers to stuff, OP might get confused why it's giving weird results. That depends on OP's uses though, so I added a sidenote just in case :P :)

Comment: To be more explicit about removing just the `%`, you could also replace `[:-1]` with `.rstrip('%')`. (neither is wrong, choose one that's clearer to you)

Comment: @viraptor That's a good point; I'll add that into the post as another point. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Tihs is actually a really good question. If your goal is the get a list of the percentage as a float here is a clean way you can do it without changing your logic a lot :

```
import re
elements = [u'  92.91%\n ', u'  98.71%\n ' ,u'  93.81%\n ', 'test']
scores = []
for element in elements:
    percentage = re.search(r'\d+', element)
    scores.append(float(percentage.group())/100 if percentage else None)    
print(scores)
```

**Output**

```
[0.92, 0.98, 0.93, None]
```

Note that this solution will find any percentage expression in your list, no matter the length.

Comment: This gets rid of fractional parts. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import ast
elements = [u'  92.91%\n ', u'  98.71%\n ' ,u'  93.81%\n ']
scores = []
for element in elements:
    scores.append(ast.literal_eval(element.replace('%','E-2').strip()))
return scores
```

Comment: This will raise an error if only a string is specified in the list.

Comment: did you try it. My answer works just fine if you don't add the `%`